# Loading data from xls-file, comparing it with data from db and displaying result in a datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, cells

I have a `datatable` with data from file - it will be an `ItemSource` of my `datagrid`. And i am getting a `datatable` with the same schema from the database. I want to compare this two datatables and if there are some rows in the file that exist in the DB i need to check that the values of columns are equal. If not - I need to change the `Background` of the cell to red colour. May be it will be more clear from my code below:

```
 dgrSimcards.ItemsSource = excelCards.Table.DefaultView;

            var dbsource = new Tables.ExcelCards();
            DBConnection.FillData(dbsource.Table);
            if (!dbsource.HasRows) return;
            foreach(DataRow impRow in import.Table.Rows)
            {
                var row = dbsource.Table.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(p =>string.Compare( p[dbsource.card_numberColumn.ColumnName].ToString() ,impRow[dbsource.card_numberColumn.ColumnName].ToString())==0);
                if (row != null)
                {
                    if (string.Compare(row[import.comentsColumn].ToString(), impRow[import.comentsColumn].ToString()) != 0)
                    {
                        //here is merging problem - i need to change background colour
                    }
                }


            }
```

I found that it's possible to change cell's background via BindingProperty. But I don't know how to do that in my case. Yes, I'm really want to compare data on client-side. Any advices is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used an additional class:

```
  public CardDoubleRow(DataRow mainRow, DataRow otherRow)
           {
               _mainRow = mainRow;
               _otherRow = otherRow;
           }

 public object card_number
       {
           get { return _mainRow[ExcelSimCards.CardNumber]; }
       }

       public bool NumberEquals
       {
           get
           {

               return _otherRow != null
                      && card_number.ToString().Equals(_otherRow[ExcelSimCards.CardNumber]
                                                                       .ToString(),
                                                                   StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
           }
       }
 foreach(DataRow impRow in import.Table.Rows)
            {
                var row = dbsource.Table.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(p =>string.Compare( p[dbsource.card_numberColumn.ColumnName].ToString() ,impRow[dbsource.card_numberColumn.ColumnName].ToString())==0);
                result.Add(new CardDoubleRow(impRow, row));

            }
datagridcontrol.ItemsSource=result;
```

Then for each column i bound a special cellstyle with trigger like:

```
DataTrigger tg = new DataTrigger()
                {
                    Binding = new Binding("NumberEquals"),
                    Value = false
                };
```